# How to have read_csv treat version numbers

Tags: python, pandas

I have a heap of tab-separated log files like this that I need to analyze.

```
163.116.197.120 2022-03-01  00:00:00.592    9.8 2493044316  3   en  JPN public  10.0.19042  48  64-bit  Microsoft Windows 10 Pro    2.0.50727.4927SP2-3.0.30729.4926SP2-3.5.30729.4926SP1-4.8.04084C-4.8.04084  1
181.209.195.130 2022-03-01  00:00:07.049    9.10    2540301398  2   en  GTM public  10.0.19043  100 64-bit  Microsoft Windows 10 Home Single Language   2.0.50727.4927SP2-3.0.30729.4926SP2-3.5.30729.4926SP1-4.8.04084C-4.8.04084  1
106.117.110.195 2022-03-01  00:00:11.856    9.1 3489778528  3   zh-Hans CHN public  6.1.7601    1   64-bit  Microsoft Windows 7 ×0H     2.0.50727.5420SP2-3.0.30729.5420SP2-3.5.30729.5420SP1-4.7.03062C-4.7.03062  1
```

To get just the columns I need, I use

```
df = pandas.read_csv(in_file, sep="\t", usecols=[0,1,3,6,7], dtype={"IP_Addr": str, "Date": str, "Version": str, "Lang": str, "Country": str, })
```

But when I print this dataframe, I get this result:

```
163.116.197.120  2022-03-01  9.8       en  JPN
0  181.209.195.130  2022-03-01  9.1       en  GTM
1  106.117.110.195  2022-03-01  9.1  zh-Hans  CHN
```

So despite setting the datatype to "str", "9.10" becomes "9.1". Same happens with dtype=object.

What am I missing?
Thanks.

Comment: Does your csv file contain the column header names you specified? If not the dtypes will not be considered as the columns for which you gave data types are not found. If you want to read all columns as strings, you can simply specify `dtype=str`

Answer (score 1):

`read_cvs()` threads first row as header with names of columns and you have to use `header=None` to change it

```
df = pandas.read_csv(..., header=None)
```

Second problem is that your file doesn't have line with headers

```
IP_Addr, Date, Version, Lang, Country
```

and `read_csv()` doesn't know which column is `Version` and you many need to use column's numbers instead of column's names. OR you have to add header with names.

Comment: Same problem. I have data like 9.1, 9.2, 9.3 upto 9.99 something in a dataframe column, but whenever I am taking the output dataframe as csv or excel, It is converting 9.10 as 9.1, 9.20 as 9.2, 9.30 as 9.3 etc. Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to concatenate the header to the beginning of the files, and that prevented the dtype dictionary from working. Thanks, @Stef!